# How to make same header and footer in bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to build a header and footer in bootstrap, so that the page I am at now will be marked identically.

For example, if I choose "Articles", it would be selected on the header, but I want it also be selected in the footer.

In addition, I want to be able to navigate via header or via footer. I.e. I want the both to behave in the same way.

```
<nav class="navbars navbar-inverse">      
    <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My website</a>
        </div>      

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapsable-section">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">            
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html" id="menu_linkto_home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html" id="menu_linkto_articles">Articles</a></li> 
                <li><a href="aboutUs.html" id="menu_linkto_aboutus">About us</a></li>           
            </ul>
        </div>                  
    </div>
</nav>
```

How can I do it?
Thanks!!

Comment: How about using a class name instead of an id and binding it to a jquery function?

Comment: I can do that, but dont really know how. Could you please privide more details. Thank you

Comment: Could you post your jquery code?

Comment: @praroh1, I have no jquery in my files. Cant it be done with jquery?

Comment: @Palpatim, How can :acive be used here?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it without jquery. Sorry!

Comment: Ack, brain fart! Should have said `:target`, not `:active`, sorry. If your navigation sets the URL with an anchor (e.g., clicking "Home" in the nav changes your URL to 'http://yoursite.com/#home'), then you have a good candidate for using the `:target` pseudoclass. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Atarget

Comment: @praroh1 I am ok to use jQuery (I just dont use it now). How would you advice to do it with jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You could give the same CSS class to a link in your header and footer, for example "Active":

```
<style>
    .active {
        background: #ddd;
    }
</style>
```

Header Link:

```
<a class="active" id="header-about-link" href="/about">About</a>
```

Footer Link:

```
<a class="active" id="footer-about-link" href="/about">About</a>
```

Both of these links would look the same and link to the same location.

If you need to apply this CSS class dynamically with jQuery, you could use something like this:

```
<script>
    $('#header-about-link').addClass('active');
    $('#footer-about-link').addClass('active');
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really crude version of something that works. I've intentionally used additional used class names etc. rather than DOM traversal so that you get the basic idea.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<header>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</header>
<body>
  <div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="border-radius:0px;">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="red active"><a href="#">red</a></li>
              <li class="blue"><a href="#">blue</a></li>
              <li class="green"><a href="#">green</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="box red_box" style="height:100px; width:100px; display:inherit; background-color:red"></div>

  <div class="box blue_box" style="height:100px; width:100px; display:none; background-color:blue"></div>

  <div class="box green_box" style="height:100px; width:100px; display:none; background-color:green"></div>

  <br/>
  <div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="border-radius:0px;">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="red active"><a href="#">red</a></li>
              <li class="blue"><a href="#">blue</a></li>
              <li class="green"><a href="#">green</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.red').click(function(){
      $('.box').css('display', 'none')
      $('.red_box').css('display', 'inherit')

      $('.blue').removeClass('active')
      $('.green').removeClass('active')
      $('.red').attr('class', 'red active')
    })

    $('.blue').click(function(){
      $('.box').css('display', 'none')
      $('.blue_box').css('display', 'inherit')

      $('.red').removeClass('active')
      $('.green').removeClass('active')
      $('.blue').attr('class', 'blue active')
    })

    $('.green').click(function(){
      $('.box').css('display', 'none')
      $('.green_box').css('display', 'inherit')

      $('.blue').removeClass('active')
      $('.red').removeClass('active')
      $('.green').attr('class', 'green active')
    })
  })
</script>
```